# Changing values of DIV buttons using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is a noob question:

I'm defining a button in HTML like this:

```
<div>    
    <input class="btn-change" type="button" value="Select good points" />
</div>
```

To avoid showing too many buttons I'd like the button to toggle between

```
value="Select good points"
```

and

```
value="Select bad points
```

So in javascript i'm using

```
$(".btn-change").on("click", function() {

    alert("you pressed the " + nextMark + " button");

    switch(nextMark) {
        case "bad":
            nextMark = "good"
            document.getelementsbyclassname("btn-change").value="Select good points";
            break;
        case 'good':
            nextMark = "bad"
            $("btn-change").value = "Select bad points";
            break;
    }
}
```

The nextMark var changes the colour of marks placed on a leaflet map depending on the value of the button.

The alert shows the case structure is working but the button value isn't changing - what is the correct way of doing this?

[jsfiddle right here](http://jsfiddle.net/joshctaylor/5VLJU/742/)

Comment: I don't think your value assignment in switch statements are correct. There is no getelementsbyclassname() method. [They are case sensitive] .For good case, the selector is just having btn-change without any selectors.

Comment: First of all, `document.getelementsbyclassname` does not exist (yes, _case_ is important in JS), secondly it returns a node list/collection (please go read up on what that means, and how to work with those), and finally, what’s with the weird mixture of jQuery and “vanilla” JS anyway …?

Comment: When you try to change the button text, just use `$(this).val("new text")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To assign a value to the input using JQuery you need to use `.val()` and not `.value`

```js
var nextMark = "good";
$(".btn-change").on("click", function() {

  switch (nextMark) {
    case "bad":
      nextMark = "good";
      $(".btn-change").val("Select good points");
      break;
    case 'good':
      nextMark = "bad";
      $(".btn-change").val("Select bad points");
      break;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input class="btn-change" type="button" value="Select good points" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify index to  `document.getElementsByClassName("btn-change")[0].value =` as `0`

```js
  var nextMark = "good";
    $(function(){
    $(".btn-change").on("click", function() {
        alert("you pressed the " + nextMark + " button");

        switch(nextMark) {
            case "bad":
                nextMark = "good"
               document.getElementsByClassName("btn-change")[0].value = "Select good points";
                break;
            case 'good':
                nextMark = "bad"
              document.getElementsByClassName("btn-change")[0].value = "Select bad points";
                break;
        }
    });
    })
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div>    
        <input class="btn-change" type="button" value="Select good points" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you're missing an ending `);` to close of the `… .on("click" …`.

If you are using jQuery, you need to remember to include that first (at the top in `<head>`), then you should define the JavaScript sheet later. Common practice is at the end, right before the `</body>` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
</body>
```

Next, for the alert, `nextMark` is not defined.
You can do that with `this`. when using jQuery, you should keep to it, so use `$(this)`.
 Put this inside the function to define `nextMark`:
`var nextMark = $(this);`

Once that is done, you need to get the value of it, unless it will say `you pressed the [object Object] button`. You do that by adding `.val()` at the end of the target with jQuery; so `nextMark.val()` inside the alert.

Now to make it switch, you could use a simple if-else statement to switch between the two with:

```
if (nextMark.val() == "Select good points") {
    nextMark.val("Select bad points");
} else {
    nextMark.val("Select good points");
}
```

If you want to use `switch`, then at least to make it work you need to give it what case it is. What goes inside the (…) of the switch is the case it will use to check.
If I put `switch(x)` and define `x` as `var x = 1` or `var x = "one`, we will use this to decide which case to use:
`case 1:` or `case "one":` will be executed.

```
var x = 1;
var y = "one";
switch(y) {
    case 1:
        // "y" is not 1.
        break;
    case "one":
        // "y" is "one", so this will be exectuted.
        break;
}
```

Therefore, we need to define when the button is "good" or "bad". You could do this by using the literal value, like:

```
var myMark = $(this).val();
switch(myMark) {
    case "Select bad points":
        $(this).val("Select good points");
        break;
    case 'Select good points':
        $(this).val("Select bad points");
        break;
}
```

```js
$(".btn-change").on("click", function() {

 var nextMark = $(this);
    alert("you pressed the " + nextMark.val() + " button");

    /* Optional method: */
    // if (nextMark.val() == "Select good points") {
    //  nextMark.val("Select bad points");
    // } else {
    //  nextMark.val("Select good points");
    // }

 var myMark = $(this).val(); /* or var myMark = nextMark.val(); */
    switch(myMark) {
  case "Select bad points":
   $(this).val("Select good points");
   break;
  case 'Select good points':
   $(this).val("Select bad points");
   break;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery included in this example to make it work -->

<div>    
    <input class="btn-change" type="button" value="Select good points" />
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the details - I appreciate it, I'm just getting starting in this.